# Getting method regardless of parameters

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to get method regardless of what parameters that method takes (as of now there is no method overloading and there wouldn't be in future). The only possible solution that i could come up with was

```
private Method getMethod(Class<?> clas, String methodName) {
    try {
        Method[] methods = clas.getMethods();
        for (Method method : methods) {
            if (method.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(methodName)) {
                return method;
            }
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

What i want to ask that is there a way to fetch a method regardless of its parameters ? I was looking at `clas.getMethod ("methodName", parameters)` and if i provide `null` in there it will try to fetch a method which has no parameters. Which wouldn't be no case.

Any ideas ?

**EDIT**
Thanks guys for input. In my case, i know that there would be only one method regardless of its case. The reason i am using `ignoreCase` is because the input will be coming from a developer (in other team) and he will be providing the name as a hard-coded string. So to keep things from spilling out of our hands, I am using a safe approach.

Comment: I think your approach looks like the correct one, except that `equalsIgnoreCase` looks odd since case is important in Java method names, but maybe that's what you need.  Anyway, I don't think there's another way to do it but to use `getMethods` or `getDeclaredMethods` and search yourself.  If you can use Java 8, there are some stream functions that find a match, but it's essentially the same thing.

Comment: the case matters just as much as the parameter types.

Comment: thanks. updated my question to explain my reason of using equalignorecase

Comment: No problem, I thought it might have to do with user input.  In that case, you definitely need to do the search yourself, since Java doesn't provide any methods to look for an identifier by name except using an exact, case-sensitive match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The way you've done it is the way to go. A method is identified by its signature and the signature includes the name and the parameter types.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that retrieves all methods with the specified class and method name regardless of the method's parameters:

```
public class Test
{
    private class Foo
    {
        public void bar()
        {

        }

        public void bar(String s)
        {

        }

        public void goo()
        {

        }
    }

    private static Method[] getMethods(Class<?> clazz, String methodName)
    {
        List<Method> methods = new ArrayList<Method>();

        Method[] declaredMethods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();

        for (Method declaredMethod: declaredMethods)
        {
            if (declaredMethod.getName().equals(methodName))
            {
                methods.add(declaredMethod);
            }
        }

        return methods.toArray(new Method[methods.size()]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Method[] methods = getMethods(Foo.class, "bar");

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(methods));
    }
}
```

This generates the following output:

```
[public void com.example.Test$Foo.bar(java.lang.String), public void com.example.Test$Foo.bar()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You've done just fine. This is basically the same as the solution to a similar problem I dealt with four years ago, creating a means to create callback methods in Java. The constructors for my `Callback` class were:

```
public Callback(Class<?> clazz, String methodName, Object parentObj) {
    // Find a method with the matching name
    Method[] allMethods;
    try { allMethods = clazz.getMethods(); }
    catch(SecurityException se) { allMethods = new Method[0]; }

    int count = 0;
    Method single = null;
    for(Method m : allMethods) {
        if(m.getName().equals(methodName)) {
            single = m;
            count++;
        }

        // Can't have more than one instance
        if(count > 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(clazz.getName()
                + " has more than one method named " + methodName);
    }
    if(count == 0) // No instances found
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(clazz.getName()
            + " has no method named " + methodName);

    this.parentObj = parentObj;
    this.method = single;
    this.parameters = single.getParameterTypes();
}

public Callback(
    Class<?> clazz,
    String methodName,
    Object parentObj,
    Class<?>...parameters)
{
    try { this.method = clazz.getMethod(methodName, parameters); }
    catch(NoSuchMethodException nsme) { nsme.printStackTrace(); }
    catch(SecurityException se) { se.printStackTrace(); }

    this.parentObj = parentObj;
    this.parameters = parameters;
}
```

My `Callback` class isn't really useful any more in the era of Java 8, but at the time the only real means for a "callback" in java was anonymous interface implementations, which wasn't sufficient for my use-case.

As you can see in the first constructor, it throws an exception if it finds multiple methods with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Using java streams there is a really short method of finding a method, the first match, by its name only:

```
Stream.of(type.getMethods())
.filter((m) -> m.getName().equals(searchedName))
.findFirst()
.get();
```

I think this is a short and readable possibility in this case.